# How to get a value in a multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to get a particular value from a multidimensional array. That is, I have the following

```
array = [ ['Text1', 's1'], ['Text2', 's2'], ['Text3', 's3'] ]
```

and, for example, I would like to search in the above array the string `s3` so to get the corresponding value `Text3`. The same for `s1` so to get the `Text1` and for `s2` so to get the `Text2`.

**How can I make that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For smallish arrays and infrequent lookups you can keep the array:

```
array = [ ['Text1', 's1'], ['Text2', 's2'], ['Text3', 's3'] ]
p array.rassoc('s3').first #=> 'Text3'
```

Comment: +1, wow, never seen that method before... Is there a particular reason why this is included? Because I've never seen another case like this where this would actually be useful.